# Проблема с футером

Tags: html5, css3

Здравствуйте, я начинающий верстальщик не судите строго , проблема в том что не могу прижать футер к низу страницы, он налазит на текст, перерыл весь гугл, не один способ не помогает, буду очень рад помощи и указать мою ошибку что я не правильно сделал, буду очень благодарен.
[image: footer]

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/6no51wek/2/`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Чтобы быстро отодвинуть футер вниз, достаточно добавить для класса `.news` свойство `margin: 130px;`. Так элемент .news "оттолкнет" элемент `footer`. Потому что сейчас верхний край футера как раз начинается после блока новостей.

Но это будет "костыль". В этом коде есть две критические проблемы.

1. С позиционированием и высотой элементов, задающих каркас страницы. Если в инструментах разработчика (например, в Google Chrome) вы проинспектируете страницу, и наведете мышкой на узел с футером, то увидите - браузер запутался, где же футер. Он подсвечивает его где-то выше [image: . На] Поэтому футер и не может нормально оттолкнуться от главного контента.
   В общем, надо навести порядок с высотой и позицией элементов. Я не говорю, что высоту надо указывать явно — это только помешает, потому что размер контента меняется. Но вы почитайте на эту тему, посмотрите примеры хорошей верстки.
2. С синтаксисом тегов, создающих структуру документа. Сейчас встречаются конструкции типа

   `<div class="te1">
     <a href="#">Новости
   </div>
   <div class="te2">
     КЛАНА</a>
   </div>`

Так ссылки нельзя оформлять. Вы разрываете структуру, когда после открытия тега `<a>` вы закрываете тег `<div>`. Ссылка должна или содержаться в блоке полностью, или заключать его в себя.

Поэтому исправьте и проверьте, нет ли где лишних незакрытых тегов. Проблема с футером не из-за этого, но часто непонятные ошибки вылезают из-за подобного: где-то тег не закрыли, где-то лишний и т.п.